# how can I get rid of GPT if I want to install single boot Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, gpt, grub-legacy

I have got my new laptop and want to install Ubuntu 14.04 on it(single boot system) from usb live disk. Since my disk is less than 1 TB, I want to have legacy boot and non-GPT partition. What can I do for this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is because of buggy BIOS firmware of the laptop I was working on, ThinkPad 440p. Downgrading its BIOS (to version 1.14) solved the problem as people pointed out in this link: [problem with ThinkPad 440p](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/246834)

Answer (score 0):

Having a live CD around, you could start fdisk from it a recreate the MBR. HAving your HDD on /dev/sda it would be

```
fdisk /dev/sda
```

followd by `o` -- `m` is printing help on fdisk.

P.S. Be careful as this would mean data is getting lost on hard disc.

Comment: Although this method will create something that is *technically* a valid MBR partition table, it will leave behind most of the original GPT data. This is likely to end up confusing `parted`, GParted, and other tools based on libparted. It's better to use `parted`, GParted, or `gdisk` for such a conversion; these tools will completely erase the old GPT data to ensure it doesn't come back to haunt you.

Comment: Creating partitions and making mkfs after that never caused an issue with that on my end.

Comment: `mkfs` is irrelevant. The problem is that libparted is overly-sensitive to leftover GPT data. If you've never run into that problem, then consider yourself lucky.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want a single boot system with 14.04 LTS, you can create a new `msdos` partition table using the `gparted` tool.

- First create a LiveUSB (The LiveUSB will help in the installation and it has `gparted` preinstalled)
- Then boot into your LiveUSB and run the "GParted"tool.
- When GParted opens, go to Device Menu --> Create Partition Table.
  [image]
- Set the partition type as `msdos`. Click  "Apply"

All data on your HDD will be lost and you can now install Ubuntu on your no-gpt Hdd

Comment: I tried it but it gives me an error when I want to add a partition:
path: /dev/sda1
start:2048
end: 976773119
size: 976771072 (465.76 GiB)
/dev/sda: unrecognized disk label

Comment: If you're getting such an error after following the advice in this answer, then something is wrong -- you've found a bug, your disk is physically defective, or you've made a mistake in following the directions.

Comment: @RodSmith thank you for your comment. I am sure I am following the directions in the right way and I am also sure the disk is OK because I can do what ever I want on it with a live Windows 7 CD, I don't find the problem under GNU/linux.

Comment: @RodSmith I checked my disk with Windows checkdisk and also the software provided by Lenovo for Thinkpads and there was no problem. I managed to install Windows on it and it works nice but still gives the same error when I want to partition it to Linux Ext4 file system. How can I acquire more information about what is going on and what is the problem, like logs or infos? Thanks a lot.